# Looking for "big names" that use open source WMS (like geoserver / ms4w / qgis server) for presentation

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, qgis-server, ms4w

I am looking for famous companies / "big names" (like army , goverments , city halls) that chose to use open source map servers and not paid solutions like Esri and such for a presentation I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Ordnance Survey, Great Britain's National Mapping Agency, and we use GeoServer for our web Map Service, OS OnDemand.

We also use PostgreSQL and PostGIS to store our vector data.

Comment: OS OnDemand is no longer available (withdrawn in November 2021).

Answer (score 0):

A famous name in education would be Harvard University using QGIS: http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/ui.php